# Understanding Javascript and React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

In the below code snippet from F8App, I am not able to understand what is going on, can someone explain what's going on in line 3 of code and point to resources on the web where I can read about this.

```
'use strict';

import {StyleSheet, Platform} from 'react-native';

export function create(styles: Object): {[name: string]: number} {
  const platformStyles = {};
  Object.keys(styles).forEach((name) => {
    let {ios, android, ...style} = {...styles[name]};
    if (ios && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      style = {...style, ...ios};
    }
    if (android && Platform.OS === 'android') {
      style = {...style, ...android};
    }
    platformStyles[name] = style;
  });
  return StyleSheet.create(platformStyles);
}
```

Comment: Learn about Ecma 6, nothing fancy here, just syntax.

Comment: can you explain this 'export function create(styles: Object): {[name: string]: number}'

Comment: It exports a function, that takes "array which is made of strings, with keyword name" as a parameter and that function (create) returns a number eventually. This typing is known as static typing, flow, to be exact.

Comment: here is a nice article which explains it: https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having trouble with the `type checking` that's added. That's actually not es6 but `flow`. You can read more about it [here](https://flow.org/)